# How do i display a value in % in an automated email?

Tags: google-apps-script, html-table

The automatically generated email with table does not show percentages.

I tried looking around for potential solutions but cant seem to find something that i understand.

```
 var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:80%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:12pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
 var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

 for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

 htmltable += '<tr>'; 

 for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
   if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
   else
     if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

   else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
 }

     htmltable += '</tr>';
 }

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,'' ,{htmlBody: body + htmltable + end})
```

The progress should be showed in percentages. It will display a value in decimal place up till a value of 1.Those that show 0.00% is due to =IFERROR(C6/B6,"0.00%"), as C6 = 0 & B6 = 0.

Comment: This is the link to the image : https://imgur.com/a/4bhg0AJ
Sry i cant seem to add the pic in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of cell `0.00%` as `0.00%`.

  - In your current issue, `0.00%` is retrieved as `0`.
- Number format of the column of "Progress" is the percentage.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Solution:

From your script, I'm not sure about the method for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet. But if you retrieve the values (in your script, it's `data`.) using `getValues()`, please modify this to `getDisplayValues()`. By this, `0.00%` is retrieved as `0.00%`.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Adrian Peh Thank you for replying. i'm glad your issue was resolved.